# Accessing a page in a child web application via URL from the main web site

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

We have a main classic ASP web site "www.main.com".
We have a ASP.NET MVC3 web application that is accessed via "www.main.com/app".

Is it possible to create a page in the web application and have it accessed via "www.main.com/page-from-app"?

It would also be ideal if the main web site doesn't need to be changed, or have minimal changes at most.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [URL Rewrite](http://www.iis.net/download/URLRewrite)?

Comment: On the main site, correct? We're trying not to change the main site as much as possible, if it is possible.

Comment: @rikitikitik did you read the link?  As I understand it, URL Rewrite is a plugin for IIS, so the original site would be intact.

Comment: Yes I did. When I mentioned about keeping the original site intact, I also meant keeping the site's IIS settings intact as well. Our team doesn't have the full privileges for making changes regarding anything about the main website.

Comment: @rikitikitik In that case you will have to either put the new site in a new folder (which you are already doing) or write the MVC site so it can reside in the same folders as the existing site (this means the web.config file must be shared and the folder structure must be compatible).  You could also try adding pages to the existing site which reprint the pages from the new site, but that is not something I would do.